Возможно ли из компонента Nuxt 2 изменять данные внутри файла nuxt.config.js
Всем доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой на nuxt 2-й версии.
у меня есть код в файле nuxt.config.js
gtm: {
        id: '*******',
        scriptDefer: true,
        pageTracking: true,
        enabled: true
    },

Есть ли возможность внутри какого либо компонента заменить значение enabled на false или что-то ещё.
Мне нужно сделать что-то подобии кнопки, которая будет на стороне фронта выключать gtm, вообще реально ли это?

"Мне нужно сделать что-то подобии кнопки, которая будет на стороне фронта выключать gtm" -- так на стороне фронта и выключайте.

Не совсем понял.

Ну а в чем Ваша логика? Вам нужно отключать GTM по клику для какого-то конкретного пользователя, верно? Почему Вы решили что для этого нужно менять конфиг?

Спасибо, я уже понял это.
